# Problem with LuaTeX : can't write on the .aux file at second pass

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows, plain-tex, auxiliary-files

I use MiKTeX 2.9 for Windows, format Plain eTeX. I have my own macro package which I've used for years, and I tried recently to use it with LuaTeX (included MiKTeX version) in order to use UTF-8 encoding (say). All things worked fine at the first pass and LuaTeX correctly created the `.aux` file and wrote suitable commands. But at the second pass, LuaTeX failed and output the message:

> I can't write on file luatest.aux.

My macro package uses only eTteX commands like openin/write etc. and all things work fine when compiled with pdfTeX. I believe this is only a matter of parameter setting when calling LuaTex from the command line, but what can it be ?

Comment: LuaTeX should behave exactly like PDFTeX or other TeX engines, so this looks like a bug somewhere. Or perhaps the file `luatest.aux` is opened by some process?

Comment: What directory is luatex trying to write `luatest.aux`? What if you have `luatest.tex` in your home directory?

Comment: I set the directory to be the current directory (cd foodirectory) and all things are done there. Notice that at the first pass, Luatex has no problem to create the .aux file and to write it. So, I don't think that this is a problem of directory.

Comment: @MikeTeX This error indicates that the .aux-file is open. Go to the directory where the -aux-file is, and try to deleted the it. I have often this problem with sync-files, that remains open after a failed compilation. Maybe you computer is to fast, and start the new compilation before Luatex is able to close the .aux-file. Do you use Texify or Luatex directly? In case of Texify, try compiling directly with Luatex, and with a second or two pause between the to run.

Comment: Thank you Sveinung, but I am using Luatex directly, and I compile the two passes manually (one after one), so, there cannot be a problem of computer speed.

Comment: I hate that this question (and others like it) is closed. It happens way too often and always by the same people. Please stop closing questions because they are too "local". As to my question: I'm having this issue but when using `latexmk`. It too seems to be happening on the second pass.